# Growl Notifications: How to push Growl notifications from a website?

Tags: growl

I'm wondering how I can push desktop Growl notifications from my web application to the user of my web application. I would like to use javascript, if possible, otherwise a language like Ruby or PHP would be my second choice.

Have you implemented something like this before? How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to use Ruby to push Growl notifications. I would still like to find a JavaScript solution, but if there is no way to use JavaScript, then here is a Ruby solution:

Use the `ruby-growl` gem:

```
gem install ruby-growl
```

Then in your Ruby script:

```
require 'ruby-growl'
g = Growl.new "localhost", "ruby-growl", ["ruby-growl Notification"]
g.notify "ruby-growl Notification", "It Came From Ruby-Growl", "Greetings!"
```

Also, in order for this to work, you have to enable **"Listen for incoming notifications"** and **"Allow remote application registration"** on the Network tab of the Growl Preference Pane

Comment: ...actually this might have only worked locally. I can't remember now.

Answer (score 1):

You can send Growl notifications from Javascript (with a bit of Flash as a helper, but that part is behind the scenes). Here is a test page: http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/examples/js/

Note that this only currently works on Windows - the Javascript/Flash support in Growl on the Mac is currently broken as noted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/growl-development/BNF8tcUE1kM