# How do i send browser messages even if website closed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

Facebook send me a browser message when i get a new message or friends request.

Facebook can do it even when i dont even have facebook opened in a window. Is that some kind of javascript? or browser extension?

I want to archive this on a site of us. If a user uploads a file to another user, the user that recieves the file should get a message. Even if he doenst have the website itself open. I store a remember me cookie on the users PC after they login, so they dont have to login next time.

Can i access that cookie somehow if user doenst have the website openend in a tab?

Comment: It's browser push notifications: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221203/send-desktop-notifications-in-chrome-or-firefox-from-a-closed-web-app is exacly what i was looking for thanks @epascarello