# For .net Core webApi hosted on IIS, looking for the simplest way to poke the end-user android app (PWA)

Tags: c#, push-notification

For .net Core webApi hosted on IIS, what is the simplest way to push event to the end-user app?
I do not need  to notify user holding the device (ie "push notification"); I just want the app to catch the push so it knows to silently refresh the screen with current info.  The brute force way to accomplish what I need would be to poll the webapi every 15 seconds or so, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Because of the breadth and evolution of the .net world, I've thoroughly confused as I search on how to push info event.  I see discussion on Signal-R, push-notification api on google developers, firebase,  etc etc.

I'd like to use the simplest way to send my simple poke from the server, telling the tablet to refresh itself, in reponse to, for instance, a record insert on the database.

This is a relatively simple app on Android tablets that for use inside the company, about 50 users at a time.

The webapi is written in c#, .net Core 3.1 hosted on IIS. The end-user Android tablet App, also hosted on IIS, is implemented as a progressive web app using React and run from Chrome.  The tablets are used only for my app so I have control over how the tablets are set up.  The web api program uses the MS-SQL database.

Thank you for any insight you may wish to share.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304503/asp-net-core-web-push-notifications

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0