# HTML5 Notifications Questions

Tags: html, html5-notifications

I have some questions about HTML5 notifications:

1. How do I replace the google chrome image on html5 notifications? I know I can do icon which adds an icon to the right hand side
2. Can I change the domain it comes from to say the name of the site rather than the domain?
3. Can they display even when the user is not on the webpage?

[image]

Comment: #1 - "The Chrome logo will always be displayed and cannot be replaced or altered. This is a requirement for third-party applications on macOS." https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/native-mac-os-notifications

Comment: #2 - No. #3. Yes, if the webpage is open in any other tab. If you want to register notifications even when the page is closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221203/send-desktop-notifications-in-chrome-or-firefox-from-a-closed-web-app

Comment: thanks both - ahh so that doesnt show on windows computers?

Comment: Point 1 - No it doesn't. On windows the image shows up on left.