# Browser notification when browser closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, notifications, service-worker

I am creating a project in Reactjs.
I have a list of upcoming events with the "Notify me" button.
When the user clicks on the "notify me" button for any event, the user should get a browser notification when the event will start.

**My question is:**
How to schedule notification for events?
Is it possible to get in browser notification when the browser closed?

I do not want to use Push notification. I wanted to use the local browser notification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send desktop notifications in Chrome or Firefox from a closed web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221203/send-desktop-notifications-in-chrome-or-firefox-from-a-closed-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can send notification even if the website is not opened but you can't if the browser is closed